# Setting DataValueField and DataTextField shows error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, drop-down-menu

I want to populate _PropSubtype which is a dropdown list by selecting a value from the another dropdown list which is _PropType, by looking at the query you will understad. The problem which is arising is that how do i set the DataValueField and DataTextField(**text to display in the dropdown list**). so far the code which i have tried is:

```
protected void _PropType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      using (Property_dbDataContext context = new Property_dbDataContext())
        {
            var type = (from a in context.Property_subtypes
                        where a.main_type == _PropType.SelectedItem.ToString()
                        select new
                        {   
                            a.sr_no,
                            a.prop_subtype

                        }
        ).Distinct().ToList();
            
            _PropSubtype.DataSource = type;
            _PropSubtype.DataValueField = type[0].sr_no.ToString();
            _PropSubtype.DataTextField = type[1].prop_subtype.ToString();            
            _PropSubtype.DataBind();         
        }
}
```

Now i have a save button which saves the Selected value of both the dropdown lists, but again problem with _PropSubtype, it may store the text but not the value as the valuefield is sr_no. here is the code for it:

```
protected void save_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Property_dbDataContext context = new Property_dbDataContext())
        {
            Property basic = new Property();
            basic.property_type = _PropType.SelectedValue;
            basic.property_subtype = _PropSubtype.SelectedIndex.ToString();
            basic.property_subtype = _PropSubtype.SelectedValue;

            context.Property.InsertOnSubmit(basic);
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

the error which ott return after selecting an option from _PropType:

> ***DataBinding:** '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'
> does not contain a property with the name 'Industrial Land'.*
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding:
> '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String,
> mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' does not contain a property with
> the name 'Industrial Land'.

Comment: Shouldn't there be properties for anonymous types?

Comment: @deostroll sorry i did not get u...

Comment: the select on your linq should be like `... select new { ar_no = a.sr_no, prop_type = a.prop_type}`...(?)